# Send object in Bundle Android

Tags: android, object, bundle, retrofit2

I have some troubles trying to pass an object received from my api to a specific Fragment, this object is a json from the API and it's dynamic, it can returns a json like:

`{
   "number1" : "45545455",
   "number2" : "58454556",
   "email1"  : "test@test.com",
   "email2"  : "test2@test2.com",
   "name"    : "Fett Shop",
   "description" : "Big sales"
}`

This json is always changing, so it can comes without number2 or email2, or another example it can comes with a third or fourth email or number.
In my OnResponse method i get the response and i save it in a Object:

```
            @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse resp = response.body();


            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {

                Object test2 = resp.getResponse();
                //In this part i was trying passing the object with Bundle
                goToContact();
            }
        }
```

I was reading to pass in a Bundle creating a class with Serialized or Parcelable,but i dont have any idea how to pass this dynamic Object to another  Fragment.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: one workaround can be get json object and convert to string then pass through intent, but i'm guessing its not the correct way

Comment: So what do you recommend? @rookieDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Objects can be passed among fragment and Activities by making the model class Serializable or Parcelable.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse resp = response.body();


            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                Object test2 = resp.getResponse();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("Object", test2 );
                fragment.setArguments(bundle); 
            }
        }
```

To get it from bundle in another fragment use in your onCreate function:

```
Object newObject = (NewObject) bundle.getParcelable("Object");
```

Comment: The problem is that i dont use a model class, because i dont know how many data comes in the json from the API

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a single object of response in the bundle.

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
        ServerResponse resp = response.body();


        if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {

            Object test2 = resp.getResponse();
            //In this part i was trying passing the object with Bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("number1", test2.getString("number1");
            bundle.putString("number2", test2.getString("number2");
            bundle.putString("email1", test2.getString("email1");
            bundle.putString("email2", test2.getString("email2");
            goToContact();
        }
    }
```

not pass the bundle in Fragment.

> YourFragment newFragment = new YourFragment();
> newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

get Data passed in Fragment.

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
String number1 = b.getString("number1");
String number2 = b.getString("number2");
String email1 = b.getString("email1");
String email2 = b.getString("email2");
```